# Connecting wall endpoints

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, computational-geometry

I have the following list of points that represent walls:

```py
walls = [[  76.7403, 1283.2495,  894.5198, 1310.0122],
        [ 864.3867,  415.2406,  891.3730, 1287.3810],
        [  80.0975,  402.9981,  899.7578,  428.0596],
        [  75.9861,  404.3390,  101.6148, 1292.0922],
        [ 469.9275, 1118.6304,  481.1644, 1300.6523],
        [ 500.6000,  897.3496,  876.6120,  908.2079],
        [ 102.0548,  753.6523,  402.9403,  764.0107],
        [ 247.2823,  968.0134,  320.4769,  977.5980],
        [ 503.2201,  898.0987,  515.2742, 1136.6272],
        [ 400.9270,  689.1513,  411.8462,  907.2622],
        [ 353.0995, 1123.1868,  362.8233, 1293.9554],
        [ 248.6094,  967.5870,  261.0458, 1124.8018],
        [ 246.0828,  896.9332,  411.2629,  906.4570],
        [ 880.6799,   60.5249,  892.5886,  411.2219],
        [ 249.5214, 1116.5377,  259.7009, 1290.2698],
        [ 309.1409,  899.7199,  320.3546,  978.5977],
        [  85.6537, 1118.2689,  259.5562, 1128.9491],
        [ 249.0276,  763.1385,  261.5212,  905.9616],
        [  86.2850, 1117.8192,  501.5602, 1128.5548],
        [ 240.1799, 1117.4913,  385.9280, 1128.2761],
        [ 288.5830, 1117.4141,  515.1036, 1128.3738],
        [ 512.2842, 1015.8013,  592.7465, 1022.5025],
        [ 249.2041,  748.7802,  260.6894, 1140.3009],
        [ 401.1811,  687.2712,  411.9943,  779.8344],
        [ 380.8932, 1040.3300,  386.9687, 1126.2324]]
```

I'm forming a set of polygons from these walls with the following:

```py
polys = []
for w in walls:
  x0, y0, x1, y1 = w
  poly = [
            (x0, y0), (x1, y0),
            (x1, y1), (x0, y1)
        ]
  poly = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(poly))
  polys.append(poly)
```

The polygons end up looking as follows:

[image]

What I would like to do is connect the wall endpoints such that they wouldn't overlap as seen in the picture. What would be an optimal algorithm to do this?

Here is the code to produce the image:

```html
<svg width="1200" height="1300">
<polygon points='76.7403, 1283.2495, 894.5198, 1283.2495, 894.5198, 1310.0122, 76.7403, 1310.0122'/>
<polygon points='864.3867, 415.2406, 891.373, 415.2406, 891.373, 1287.381, 864.3867, 1287.381'/>
<polygon points='80.0975, 402.9981, 899.7578, 402.9981, 899.7578, 428.0596, 80.0975, 428.0596'/>
<polygon points='75.9861, 404.339, 101.6148, 404.339, 101.6148, 1292.0922, 75.9861, 1292.0922'/>
<polygon points='469.9275, 1118.6304, 481.1644, 1118.6304, 481.1644, 1300.6523, 469.9275, 1300.6523'/>
<polygon points='500.6, 897.3496, 876.612, 897.3496, 876.612, 908.2079, 500.6, 908.2079'/>
<polygon points='102.0548, 753.6523, 402.9403, 753.6523, 402.9403, 764.0107, 102.0548, 764.0107'/>
<polygon points='247.2823, 968.0134, 320.4769, 968.0134, 320.4769, 977.598, 247.2823, 977.598'/>
<polygon points='503.2201, 898.0987, 515.2742, 898.0987, 515.2742, 1136.6272, 503.2201, 1136.6272'/>
<polygon points='400.927, 689.1513, 411.8462, 689.1513, 411.8462, 907.2622, 400.927, 907.2622'/>
<polygon points='353.0995, 1123.1868, 362.8233, 1123.1868, 362.8233, 1293.9554, 353.0995, 1293.9554'/>
<polygon points='248.6094, 967.587, 261.0458, 967.587, 261.0458, 1124.8018, 248.6094, 1124.8018'/>
<polygon points='246.0828, 896.9332, 411.2629, 896.9332, 411.2629, 906.457, 246.0828, 906.457'/>
<polygon points='880.6799, 60.5249, 892.5886, 60.5249, 892.5886, 411.2219, 880.6799, 411.2219'/>
<polygon points='249.5214, 1116.5377, 259.7009, 1116.5377, 259.7009, 1290.2698, 249.5214, 1290.2698'/>
<polygon points='309.1409, 899.7199, 320.3546, 899.7199, 320.3546, 978.5977, 309.1409, 978.5977'/>
<polygon points='85.6537, 1118.2689, 259.5562, 1118.2689, 259.5562, 1128.9491, 85.6537, 1128.9491'/>
<polygon points='249.0276, 763.1385, 261.5212, 763.1385, 261.5212, 905.9616, 249.0276, 905.9616'/>
<polygon points='86.285, 1117.8192, 501.5602, 1117.8192, 501.5602, 1128.5548, 86.285, 1128.5548'/>
<polygon points='240.1799, 1117.4913, 385.928, 1117.4913, 385.928, 1128.2761, 240.1799, 1128.2761'/>
<polygon points='288.583, 1117.4141, 515.1036, 1117.4141, 515.1036, 1128.3738, 288.583, 1128.3738'/>
<polygon points='512.2842, 1015.8013, 592.7465, 1015.8013, 592.7465, 1022.5025, 512.2842, 1022.5025'/>
<polygon points='249.2041, 748.7802, 260.6894, 748.7802, 260.6894, 1140.3009, 249.2041, 1140.3009'/>
<polygon points='401.1811, 687.2712, 411.9943, 687.2712, 411.9943, 779.8344, 401.1811, 779.8344'/>
<polygon points='380.8932, 1040.33, 386.9687, 1040.33, 386.9687, 1126.2324, 380.8932, 1126.2324'/>
</svg>
```

Comment: add the code to plot the image

Comment: I'm not using any lib for that. Simply ```for p in polys:
  print(f"<polygon points='{str(p).strip('[]')}'/>")``` and then you can use something like https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_svg_circle to plot the svg.

Comment: Also make sure you specify the dimensions for the svg correctly, for this particular sample 1200x1300 should do.

Comment: With your given walls values, most of your lines are slanting. But the image you shown have perfect vertical and horizontal lines. Have you done something to do that?

Comment: The image is formed from the polygons.

Comment: Those are also the same values. It should be producing slanting lines

Comment: You should be able to reproduce the results with the given code. Forming the polygons corrects the slantness of the points.

Comment: Please provide all the code you use to produce the image.

Comment: Afk right now, my second comment should work to produce the image.

Comment: @scleronomic Added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear what your final goal is.
Which of the lines do you want to cut? All loose ends or just the ones that are a little bit too long? And what about the different thicknesses of the lines?

The simplest thing I came up with is to convert the `walls` to lines with a specific width and than to discretize the end points of those lines, this way the resulting image looks a little bit cleaner:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def walls2lines(walls):
    lines = []
    widths = []
    for w in walls:
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = w
        if (x1-x0) > (y1 - y0):
            widths.append(y1-y0)
            lines.append(((x0, y0 + widths[-1] / 2), (x1, y0 + widths[-1] / 2)))
        else:
            widths.append(x1-x0)
            lines.append(((x0 + widths[-1] / 2, y0), (x0 + widths[-1] / 2, y1)))

    return np.array(lines), np.array(widths)


def discretize_np(x, step):
    difference = x % step  # distance to the next discrete value
    difference[difference > step / 2] -= step  # round correctly
    return x - difference


lines, widths = walls2lines(walls=walls)
lines = discretize_np(lines, step=50)
widths *= 10 / widths.max()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.subplots()

for l, w in zip(lines, widths):
    ax.plot(*l.T, lw=w, alpha=0.5)
```

[image: lines]

Another possibility is to really look at the overlaps of different rectangles and try to shift the respecting boundaries. But you have so many different cases that it is hard to find a good general solution and it really depends on what you are looking for.

I added an `eps` to `walls2overlap` to also include rectangles that do not quite intersect. And I commented a line to handle the free ends differently.
A lot of fine tuning and trial and error...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection


def walls2overlap(walls, eps=0):

    idx_overlap = np.ones((len(walls), len(walls)), dtype=bool)
    for i, w_i in enumerate(walls):
        for j, w_j in enumerate(walls):
            (x0_i, x1_i), (y0_i, y1_i) = w_i
            (x0_j, x1_j), (y0_j, y1_j) = w_j
            if (x0_i > x1_j+eps or x1_i < x0_j-eps or
                y0_i > y1_j+eps or y1_i < y0_j-eps):
                idx_overlap[i, j] = False

    return idx_overlap


def get_orientations(walls):
    """
    0: horizontal, 1: vertical
    """
    (x0, x1), (y0, y1) = walls.transpose(1, 2, 0)
    return ((x1 -x0) < (y1 - y0)).astype(int)


def cut_walls(walls, idx_overlap):
    """Move the walls to the most extreme boundary
     of all intersecting walls of different orientation."""
    for i, w_i in enumerate(walls):
        o_i = orientations[i]
        idx_temp = np.logical_and(idx_overlap[i], orientations != o_i)
        if idx_temp.sum() <= 0:  # Set to 1, to keep free ended walls
            continue
        walls[i, o_i, 0] = np.min(walls[idx_temp, o_i, 0])
        walls[i, o_i, 1] = np.max(walls[idx_temp, o_i, 1])

    return walls


walls = np.reshape(walls, (-1, 2, 2), order='F')
idx_overlap = walls2overlap(walls=walls, eps=10)
orientations = get_orientations(walls)
walls = cut_walls(walls=walls, idx_overlap=idx_overlap)

fig, ax = new_fig(aspect=1)
rects = [Rectangle(xy=w[:, 0], width=w[0, 1] - w[0, 0], height=w[1, 1] - w[1, 0])
         for w in walls]
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(rects, color='k', alpha=0.5))
```

[image: rectangles]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second script you provided seems to be exactly something I was looking for. However you were concerned about the generalization of this, I haven't tested it yet, but if you could elaborate on what were your main concerns that would be very helpful :)

Comment: I am glad, I could help. If you just want to cut all loose ends, this should work quite well. However, as you can see on the dark spots, this algorithm produces some really small rectangles, which maybe should be removed completely. And I do not handle the line widths, because I do not know what behaviour you expect here. You can see on the left boundary of the smallest rectangle, that there is still room for improvement ;)